# Is the following binary relation transitive?: (x,y)R(u,v) iff x*y - u*v ≥ 1, where R represents at least as good as.

Tags: relations

So, we have the binary relation defined by (x,y)R(u,v) iff x*y - u*v ≥ 1, where R represents at least as good as.

What I already have is:

For any (x,y), (u,v), (r,t) in X (the alternatives set),

[(x*y-u*v≥1)^(u*v-r*t≥1)] -> (x*y-r*t≥1)     I need to prove this.

I started by setting:

(u*v≤1+x*y)^(u*v≥1+r*t) -> 1+r*t ≤ u*v ≤ 1+x*y -> 1+r*t ≤ 1+x*y -> r*t ≤ x*y

This last line doesn't prove or disprove if the function is transitive but I don't know what else to do.